# amplify api add-graphql-datasource authorization issue

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I am following instructions on [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/relational/) but it returns me this error:

```
 There was an error adding the datasource
 User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/us-east-1_ocb0gotWz_Full-access/amplifyadmin is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBClusters on resource: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:xxx:cluster:* because no identity-based policy allows the rds:DescribeDBClusters action
```

how can this be resolved? I am using admin user and have all the permissions.

Comment: Are the role and resource in the same account?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it looks like when I did `amplify init` I used amplify profile that I had, and, db was created by admin user, so it was complaining that that.